# Can I modify a text file while a program has it open, in C++?

Tags: c++, io

I have a class that, when created, opens a file.

And on each update, it reads each line of the file and extracts a key and a value.

It compares the value with a reference value that it has in an internal variable, and if the value is different, it fires an event.

The idea is that, manually and with the program running, I open the text file, modify a value and the program detects it, but that doesn't happen. It doesn't detect it. It is as if the instance of the file that I open and the one that has the program open are different.

Do I have to open the file on each update? Now I keep it open from when the class is created until it is destroyed.

Comment: That depends on how the file was opened. If it was opened in shared write mode, you can. If not, you can't. It also depends on how the second app is written to open the file.

Comment: This question may have some OS specific solutions.

Comment: The behavior is likely different depending on how the file is changed.  Eg some text editors don’t overwrite the file, rather they create a new file, then rename the old file, then rename the new file to the user’s filename, then delete the old file.  In that scenario there really are two files.

Answer (score 4):

> I have to open the file on each update?

The C++ standard does not specify how file streams behave when the file is modified externally. As discussed in comments, seeking to the beginning of the file *may* be sufficient to read the changed content, in which case re-opening won't be necessary.

Comment: That's not true, at least on Windows. You can register for notifications on file modifications, and then re-read the file if needed.

Comment: @KenWhite Through the previously opened stream?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that comment. In the OP's example, app A has the file open, and app B (some other app) opens the same file and modifies it and saves the changes. App A receives a notification that the file has been modified, and reads the changes in the file. App A does not have to close and reopen the file; it can just reposition back to the beginning of the file and read again. You could also do the same with a memory-mapped file that is opened by both apps.

Comment: @KenWhite I've modified the answer correspondingly.